# Angular 2 - Graph not getting plotted(two dimensional ) , ng2-charts(working properly in other pages)

Tags: angular, graph, ng2-charts

i'm trying to plot a graph using ng2-charts, its working properly in other pages which i plot single array, when it comes to two dimensional it not plotting,the code i used is given below

**.ts**

...................

```
 public barChartOptions:any = {
  scaleShowVerticalLines: false,
  responsive: true,
};

public barChartLabels:string[] = ['20-30', '31-40', '41-50', '51-60', '61+'];
public barChartType:string = 'bar';
public barChartLegend:boolean = true;
public reportChartData:any[] =  [
  {label: 'Series A'},
  {label: 'Series A'}
];
```

...............

```
private fetchreportDaily(dateofSales = new Date()){

    var self = this;
    self.reportdate = dateofSales.toISOString().split('T')[0];
    console.log('inside', self.reportdate)
    self.reportDaily = self.analyticsService.getclientreport(self.shopId , self.reportdate)
    self.reportDaily.subscribe((res:any) => {

    let reportToday_result = self.graphPlotting(res);
    self.reportChartData[0]['data'] = reportToday_result[0];
    self.reportChartData[1]['data'] = reportToday_result[1];

    console.log('Result',reportToday_result)
  });
  }
  private graphPlotting(res){
  console.log(" inside graphPlotting")
  let graphValues=[];
  let barChartData1 = res.map(o => {
  return o.male;
  });
  let barChartData2 = res.map(o => {
  return o.female;
  });
  console.log(barChartData1,barChartData2);
  graphValues[0]=barChartData1;
  graphValues[1]=barChartData2;
  return graphValues;
  }
```

**.Html**

```
 <canvas baseChart
     [datasets]="reportChartData"
     [colors]="colors"
     [labels]="barChartLabels"
     [options]="barChartOptions"
     [legend]="barChartLegend"
     [chartType]="barChartType" >
</canvas>
```

**Console**
[image]
[image]